# Display list of custom taxonomies from a custom post type ordered by their parent

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm not quite sure the question explains my point. And it's interesting to have a look at this [previous answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69302/sort-posts-by-custom-taxonomy-name/149348#149348), since the code to display the custom taxonomies is explained in there.

What I need is to display the child item category under his father, but I can't figure it out. What I'm creating is a list of books under every category I've created.

I have my custom category and it's related to a custom post type which have additional custom meta boxes, in my this case, for books.

When making the query, it's working well, but I have two issues:

The first is, because I really don't know how to display the child under his father, actually the child is displayed as another category as the others and its totally separated from his father.

And the same query is displaying post both, under the father category as the child category. So it seems to be kind of duplicated in my list: being the "astrological" the father category it has a child named "stars". So in my list, the category "astrological" has 2 post related to it, but that's because its displaying the post related to it and the post related to his child, which is "stars".

Explained best is:

> ASTROLOGICAL (father)  (has one post related, "Aquarium")
>
> -STARS (child) (has one post related, "Andormeda")

What I see being displayed is a list in this way:

> ASTROLOGICAL
>
> -Aquiarium
>
> -Andormeda
>
> ANOTHER CATEGORY
>
> -his post related
>
> STARS
>
> -Andormeda

Don't know if I was clear, so I post my code for the query...

As you can see above categories is for giving an example, actually my query is for books but its in spanish, that's why I'm using the "astrological" example.

```
<?php
             $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
             $autor = $custom["autor"][0];
             $editorial = $custom["editorial"][0];
           ?>

   <?php
//for a given post type, return all
$post_type = 'Libro';
$tax = 'categoria_libro';
$tax_terms = get_terms($tax);

if ($tax_terms) {
  foreach ($tax_terms  as $tax_term) {
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => $post_type,
      "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
  );


    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul class="cat"><h3> '. $tax_term->name. '</h3>';

      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> <?=$autor?> <?=$editorial?></a></li>



        <?php endwhile;?>
  </ul>
    <?php }
    wp_reset_query();
  }
}
?>
```

.....EDITED......

With my code this is what is displaying [Link actual displaying](http://dianalevy.tk/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202014-06-22%2011.15.32.png)
Notice that in my backend the category "energia" is actually a child of "herramientas terapueticas"

And what I want is to [display this](http://dianalevy.tk/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/libros_2.png)

The category "herramientas terapeuticas displaying its posts, and displaying too another list of its child, in this case "energia".

I really dont know how to write the code for this.

I hope this help to clear my point

Thanks in advanced!!!

Comment: Huh?  Are you asking us how to create a nested while loop? If category contents (children or adult) exist, print them out, go on to next one...

Comment: In the alternative its okay to create your own php function `post_is_eq_or_in_descendant_category( $cat_slug_names, $_post = null ) {...}`     In use that reads `if (post_is_eq_or_in_descendant_category()......`

Comment: Hint: You start at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Testing_if_a_post_is_in_a_descendant_category     See that function at the bottom of that page?  Use that as a basis to create your own.  I happen to like using category slug names, its easier on my brain.

Comment: Thank u very much for fast answer...as soon as I try it I´ll let you know, posting the code for other with related problems

Comment: Thank u a lot but I didn't get that to work.

Comment: mmm...Im working locally but, the problem is I do can display the custom meta box values, but still cant get filter the query results order by meta_key....

So I have my custom post type, custom taxonomy "category" and custom meta's

So in that post type I have 3 custom meta

meta_key   
           
autor              
anio

another

So what I get is a list of Categories displaying a list of posts under that category

I need the items in the list of posts (each on the `<li>`  ) be order by meta_key=autor    


I hope I can make myself clear enough, and thanks for your patience and ethusiasm

Comment: Its not exactly clear on what you are trying to do.  Can you provide a sample of your expected output?  (just edit your original question, add a section for expected output.)  I think you are trying to format results from the_loop in a convenient way, but its really not clear.  What does success on your website look like?  Is it something like this? `http://unserkaiser.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/book_review_mockup.png`

Comment: Yes, sorry...as Im a new user i was not aware of how to use the forum and most of my question was delteted cause I was asking in the answers...so the question now is very uncompleted and not understanding. Sorry for all that and many thanks to try to help me. I really wasnt able to output the children of a parent, as the main question but I did get to sokve the query for filter my results as I wanted. Do I have to answer with my solution?

Comment: I recently edited my question to show an example of expected output... hope it helps to clear my poitn...thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/150142/31545). I suspect that this might be what you are looking for