# Sorting Posts by Taxonomy thats not within the query's $args

Tags: wp-query, array, sort

I’m displaying posts currently using the WP_Query, which doesn’t include the state taxonomy within the $args because I do not want the state to be within the query. But I do want to display the state. I’m displaying the post’s corresponding state taxonomy via get_the_term_list($post->ID, ‘state’).  My task is how to use WordPress functions to display the posts alphabetically by the state taxonomy.

I'm thinking I can include the value from the corresponding state taxonomy and include it within a new array which will also include the WP_Query post data that I want to display as well. Then I can use PHP's usort() function to sort through the new array by state taxonomy.

I'm having trouble executing this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Wordpress doesn't have a built-in way to sort by taxonomy term. You do, though, have a couple of options.

1. You can iterate through your taxonomy terms and run a separate wp_query for each as [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69302/sort-posts-by-custom-taxonomy-name) shows.
2. You can directly manipulate the SQL query to achieve what you want. [This article](http://scribu.net/wordpress/sortable-taxonomy-columns.html) shows how. Look particularly at the last, Direct JOINs method.