# Order archive custom posts by taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

I cant change the way things are, so I cant use custom meta...

I have terms that are years and I have to display the archive in order (newest to oldest-in terms, not published date) For example the terms are 2007,2008,2009. I need the posts to display first the 2009 ones then the 2008, then the 2007.

I prefer to use a function than the query call. Why? I am using a generic archive.php page, not using one for post types. I'd like to keep it that way.

I try to add a function to the theme to change the way some posts are displayed with no success. Please help me out! :D

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order');

function my_change_sort_order($query)
{
if (is_post_type_archive($post_types = 'zee_publications')):
    $query->set('order', 'desc');

    $query->set(get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'cat_publications',
        'orderby',
        'slug'
    )));
endif;
};
```

Comment: It's a great example of what I call "wishful coding" - you write some random code that makes no sense at all and wish that some magic will happen and it will work. The part `$query->set(get_terms(array(...` makes no sense at all. This method assumes first param is name of field and second is new value - you pass only one value - list of terms...

Comment: Please take a look at rules of this site. Before adding a question you should do some research by yourself. Then you should search for similar questions (you clearly haven’t, because almost the same question was asked one or two weeks ago and there are plenty other questions regarding the same issue). Then you called me a douche for giving you an answer (in form of link to exactly the same question...) Great job, really...

Comment: it is *not* the same question. I want to alter the query in functions.php

Comment: read the answers in that question with some understanding. There is no native way to sort by terms. It wont be effective and you can’t achieve it using pre_get_posts. It is clearly stated in first answer for that question.

Comment: I have read tons of questions about this, and it **can** be done, according to a lot of people, ex. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69302/sort-posts-by-custom-taxonomy-name ...but nobody uses the functions.php, so...i should delete my question then, Mr.?

Comment: using functions.php changes nothing. You can place your code in plugin, or in theme, or wherever you want to... And no, there is no way to use WP_Query parameters to sort posts by term. If you want to do this, you have to write your own SQL it is also clearly stated in second answer for the question I’ve linked here...

Answer (score 0):

### First things first... Why it doesn't work?

Your code doesn't work, because you use WP API incorrectly...

Method `set` takes exactly two arguments:

> set( $query_var, $value )
>
> Set a named query variable to a specific
>   value.

So how do you use it in your code?

```
$query->set( get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'cat_publications',
    'orderby',
    'slug'
) ) );
```

There is only one argument (so it's `$query_var` - name of variable) and you pass `get_terms` result in there...

So what is that function doing? It retrieves the terms in a given taxonomy or list of taxonomies (and it returns a list of terms).

OK, so basically your current code is creating some custom query variable with name set to array containing terms and no value.

So it should be pretty clear right now, why this code doesn't do what you want it to...

### So how to order posts by terms using WP_Query?

Let's take a look at [Order & Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). As you can see, you can order by many properties, but... Terms are not among these properties.

This is caused by database structure - ordering posts by terms wouldn't be efficient and it is so rare, that there is no point in implementing it.

So how to do it? You can't - there is no way to use WP_Query to order posts by terms. It doesn't matter if you create your own `WP_Query` loop, or if you use `pre_get_posts` (as you do) to modify global `$wp_query` instance...

### So is it really impossible?

No, of course it is possible. You can always take control over raw SQL that given WP_Query is creating and modify it.

cenk posted an example of such query in his answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/136825/34172

Of course you don't have to use it as raw query. You can use `posts_clauses` filter to add missing SQL parts to the query generated by your WP_Query.

But it won't be efficient and it won't be easy to implement it correctly. There are many boundary conditions and many things can go wrong (what if some posts have multiple terms, etc.)

### And you can also cheat a little bit

WP_Query can order posts by meta value. So you can store term name as meta value with save_post hook and then sort posts by this meta value...